# Can Java have dynamic type binding for variables?

Tags: java, dynamic-binding, static-binding

Can variables have dynamic type binding in Java? I know that methods can, but I don't think that variables can since every variable has to have a type declaration when it is created such as int, double, or float. If they can, how would that be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Java 10, the `var` keyword was introduced to allow **local variable** *type inference*, which means the type for the local variable will be inferred by the compiler, so you don’t need to declare that. For example,

```
var myNum=0;// At this moment, compiler interprets as an integer
```

So if later on you attempt to assign a `String` value to it, it will throw an error. Notice that I emphasize this to be true only of local variables.